# How to embed WMV video file in my Joomla! page or HTML

Tags: html, joomla, embed, wmv

I have a Joomla! site that I need to embed a WMV video in it. I want it to be playable.

I have AllVideos Joomla! Plugin installed and it has the function to play WMV files, but when I try to play it there is a sign that I have to install Microsoft Silverlight. Now, for me that isn't a big problem, but I do not want to make my visitors install it just to watch a video.

So, if any of you have a solution to embed it using a Joomla! extension or an HTML/HTML5 solution, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transcode your videos from WMV to an open format suitable to be played by the browser without a plugin. WMV is a proprietary format, you'd be better off transcoding the videos to webM, OGG or MP4 even. Here is the [list of formats supported by Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

To transcode you can either have a batch script server side or you can use a service like [Kaltura](http://exchange.kaltura.com/content/video-extension-joomla) with their Joomla extension.

Comment: Good suggestions, another conversion option that I use regularly is Handbrake: http://download.cnet.com/HandBrake/3000-2140_4-43951.html

Comment: Thanx! But it is a HUGE movie and i won't go through the trouble of converting and uploading again... I'll just embed the YouTube video...